# Laravel one API Endpoint with different request validation

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm creating an API that needs to be one entry point for at least two purposes for now.

My `api.php`

```
Route::post('/action', 'Api\ActionApiController@process')->name('action');
```

This url will accept post data in json type. Based on this json, I'll have different validation that needs to apply differently on this json data.

For example

```
{
   "type" : 1,
   "data1" : "B",
   "data2" : "C"
}
```

The logic should come like this

if type == 1 then data1 is mandatory and data2 is optional. But if type == 2 then data1 is optional and data2 is mandatory.

So far i'm creating two custom request with different validation function, because I don't want to bloat my validation function with many if just in case the `type` needs to be extended

So I came with two class

```
class Data1Request extends FormRequest {
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data1'           => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

and another class

```
class Data2Request extends FormRequest {
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'data2'           => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

and finally my controller

```
public function process(Request $request){
   //check type: it is okay for me to put many if here, because this is only casting things to its type
  if($request->input('type') == 1) {
     //where should I cast my request and validate it?
  }

}
```

So where and how should I casting Request variable to my custom class and validate it? or should I go with many if(s) way?

Added:

Comment: Check ```required_if``` validation in laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: interesting, I just know that there is such validation, but shouldn't it be hard to read and implement if there is some nested logic on it? for example required if type == 1 && (type ==2 || type == 3) ?

Comment: In above case you have to build rules array according to your condition and return it in ```FormRequest```. You can access submitted data using ```$this```